# Conditional Sentence(simple present mode or future tense)

Tags: conditional-constructions

Would you please tell me if I use "If you will be selected*" instead of "If you are selected", does it make sense? Would please tell me the differences between these two tenses?

Thank you for your reply.  I note that you are planning to take your IELTS test in April and will advise the shortlist panel of this.   If **you are selected** for interview, we will be in contact after the closing date of 15st August 2019.

Comment: You can never put *will* in the *if* part except for rare cases unrelated to futurity.

Comment: Amir, did you abandon this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are selected=implies a condition that may occur in the future. The idea is hypothetical, but the verb tense is present, in this case, a present passive tense.

If you will be selected=is not grammatical in English.

For simple conditional sentences, never use will after if, use the present.

If he passes the test, they will let him into the university.

Notice: the will is in the second clause (main clause).

Answer (score 0):

"If you will be selected" implies that it has already been determined who will be selected. Which doesn't really make sense, since if you've determined who will be selected, then you've selected them. There are cases where this construction makes sense, for instance "If you will be taking the test, please advise the panel". In that context, "will be taking" essentially means "are planning to take".

Answer (score 0):

By far the more usual and idiomatic way of writing this would be to say ***If you are selected for interview, we will be in contact...***

You could in this particular case, use what many describe as the subjunctive form ***If you be selected...***. But in such a simple sentences as this it would be unusual.

It would be more appropriate with something like *If in the very difficult circumstances, you be so minded as to travel three-hundred miles for interview, then by all means let us know*.